# SharePoint 2013 Mobile view

Tags: 2013, mobile

I am trying to design 2013 site as mobile view for this I have used device channels, I figure out way for mobiles and Ipad but unable detect Android tablets, is there way that without using user agent string, I can detect android tablets.

Answer (score 0):

The User Agent string was invented to identify the program/os/device making the request. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

You can force a specific device channel via a cookie or querystring, but to really identify the remote device requires parsing the user agent.